Why does a cantilever beam bend instead of shearing when a point load is applied?
I have just learnt about cantilever beams and that they are free on one end and supported on the other. In my class, my teacher showed an example of when we apply a point load at the end of a cantilever beam and how it bends.
I also know about shearing stress, where when two antiparallel forces act tangential to the surfaces they act on, cause a shearing deformation.
My question is that why, (ignoring gravity) when we apply a point load on one end of the beam it doesn't cause a shearing deformation? Since, there is the point load on one side and the resistive force of the support on the other, both acting opposite to each other and parallel to the faces of the sides of the beam?
I understand that we can derive the equation for the deflection at any point along the beam using the flexure formula, but my question is why does it even produce a degree 2 polynomial (in this case) instead of a linear function?

Why do you think there isn't a shear stress?

That's not what I meant, I know there are shear stresses. But my question is why does the beam bend instead of shearing. I am referring to the deformations caused.

I see, well it does both. I guess I should have asked why you imagine that bending somehow excludes shear stress.

A lateral load on a beam does cause shear stress and thus shear strain and shear deformation.
If a model doesn’t consider that effect (e.g., in Euler–Bernoulli beam theory), it’s typically because the shear deformation is assumed to be negligible relative to the bending deformation that arises from the applied moment.
More sophisticated models (and numerical finite-element solutions) may incorporate and include the shear.
Example: consider a cantilever beam with square cross section $h\times h$ and length $L$:

The area moment of inertia is $I=\frac{h^4}{12}$. For a (Young's modulus) stiffness of $E$ and typical Poisson ratio of $\frac{1}{4}$, say, the shear modulus is $G=\frac{2E}{5}$.
For a point end load of $F$, the shear stress is $\frac{F}{h^2}$. Applying small-angle approximations, the resulting shear strain $\frac{F}{Gh^2}$ tilts the beam downward with end deformation $\frac{FL}{Gh^2}=\frac{5FL}{2Eh^2}\sim \frac{FL}{Eh^2}$.
The bending moment increases moving away from the point load to a maximum of $FL$ at the support. This bending moment causes the beam to curve downward with deformation $\frac{FL^3}{3EI}=\frac{4FL^3}{Eh^4}\sim \frac{FL^3}{Eh^4}$.
So the scaling relation we're comparing is $\frac{L}{h^2}$ vs. $\frac{L^3}{h^4}$, or $h^2$ vs. $L^2$. If the beam is much longer than it is tall ($L\gg h$), then the former, corresponding to the shear deformation, is insignificant compared to the latter, corresponding to the bending deformation.

I have read examples where the bending moment varies along the beam (due to the presence of a point load) and I understand that this causes the "bending", yet why does the bending moment vary along the beam? Shouldn't it be constant since there is only a single force acting (at the end of the beam)?

And perhaps I should be explicit; that I expect the beam to deform solely based on shearing.

I recommend reviewing bending moments. The need to balance the end load leads to a tensile stress on one side of the beam and a compressive stress on the other. This produces bending.

Draw the bending moment and shear force diagram of a cantilever including moment at the fixed built-in end.
At any point distant from free end,
$$ M= -F\cdot x,~~ \text{shear force is constant = $F$}$$
which is varying, shown linearly in a triangular variation plot .
Curvature
$$ y^{''}(x)= \frac{M}{EI}= -F\cdot x~$$
which produces a third degree polynomial on integration for deflection leading to the formula
$$ y_{max}=\frac{FL^3}{3 EI}$$
For action of shear flow / stress please try to understand  text-book formula $ \dfrac{VQ}{It}$ derivation. The shear force $V$ is constant shown in a rectangular plot.
For sufficiently high $t$ thickness (deep) beams effect of shear deformation is of course present, but can be neglected.
